# Line break after opening brace in do-while in Resharper instead of before

Tags: c#, resharper, code-formatting

I use Resharper a lot and I love it for the most part, but I use Whitesmiths style braces for method bodies and their sub-blocks and I'd like to keep the opening brace on the same line as "do" in do-while blocks.

Here's what Resharper does:

```cs
do
    {
    /* body */
    }
while (true);
```

Here's how I'd like it to look:

```cs
do {
   /* body */
   }
while (true);
```

I don't think there's an option for this in Resharper, are there any other tools that I can use to do this when I format my code, or at least prevent Resharper from changing it?

Comment: There is no option to achieve this with ReSharper currently. You can turn off auto-formatting options in ReSharper (type "Auto-format" in R# options search box). I think you can use Visual Studio built-in formatter for that, just turn-on "Indent open and close braces" and turn off "Place open brace on new line..." options.